# certificate.php:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: TEstasdasd is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

**my php code**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $all_info = $name . "<br>" . $address . "<br>" . $fname . "<br>" . $fname;
    // echo $all_info;
}

// echo $name,$email,$message;

?>
```

**my js code**

```
<script>

const name = <?php echo $name ?>;
console.log(name);
alert(name);


</script>
```

**error**

> certificate.php:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: TEstasdasd is not defined

**eror sources code**

```
<script>

const name = TEstasdasd;
console.log(name);
alert(name);


</script>
```

> I can't fix my bugs can anyone help me?

Comment: try to wrap the name into quotes ie `const name = 'TEstasdasd';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const name = TEstasdasd;` on this line you're getting error. Because you didn't define it anywhere and try to call that constant

Try as below.

```
const name = 'TEstasdasd';
```